# Unmodifiable Vector in Java

Tags: java

I need to manage data in my program where Java-Vector suits the purpose as it is synchronized,provides dynamic size and fast random access through index.

But I want to make my Vector Read Only for other Program Classes and Read Write for my own Class.

I read about `Collections.unmodifiableList()` ,but if I make my `Vector` unmodifiable, it will become read-only to my class as well.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I read about `Collections.unmodifiableList()`, but if I make my Vector unmodifiable, it will become read-only to my class as well.

I think you misunderstand what that method does.  In reality, it creates an unmodifiable *wrapper* for the existing list, leaving the original list modifiable.

So the way to handle your requirement is to do something like this<sup>1</sup>:

```
private Vector<?> myVector = new Vector<?>();
private List<?> readOnly = Collections.Collections.unmodifiableList((myVector);

public List<?> getList() { return readOnly; }
```

Anything that has access to `myVector` can still add and remove elements from it.  The changes will be visible via the `readonly` object ... but "change" operations on that object won't work.

(The other approach is to create copies of the original `Vector` object, but I'm pretty sure that doesn't meet your requirements.)

---

<sup>1 - Note that the `readOnly` object is a `List` but not a `Vector`.  This shouldn't be a problem unless you have made the mistake of declaring the getter as returning a `Vector`.  If you've done that, and you can't correct the mistake, then you will need to create your own subclass of `Vector` along the line of Evgeniy Dorofeev's answer.  Otherwise `Collections.unmodifiableList(...)` will do just fine.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Make it a `private` member of your class and only provide getters that return an immutable version of the vector as a `public` way to access it, using the function you mentioned (`Collections.unmodifiableList()`).

Answer (score 2):

If you really want an unmodifiable Vector (not just List) create a method as

```
public static Vector unmodifiableVector(Vector v) {
    return new Vector(v) {
        @Override
        public void add(int index, Object element) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized boolean addAll(Collection c) {

        @Override
        public synchronized void addElement(Object obj) {

        // ... other mutators
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Collections.unmodifiableList(myList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make vector a private member of your class. expose a public method to the callers which will get a reference to an unmodifiableCollection.

```
public Vector getVector(){
     return Collections.unmodifiableList(yourVector) ;
}
```

For use in your internal class, you can either reference the vector directly or create a `private` method which will return a reference to collection.

```
private Vector getMyVector(){
         return yourVector ;
    }
```

Comment: You'll get a cast class exception

Answer (score 0):

I think if you make your `Vector` as `private` member attribute in your along with all `write methods` as `private` while `read methods` as `public`, you would be **OK** e.g.

```
    private Vector<T> myVector = ...

    private void setMyVector(Vector<T> vector){
        myVector = vector;
    }

    private void addElement(T element){
        myVector.add(element);
    }

    public T getElement(int indx){
        return myVector.get(indx);
    }
    ....
    ....
```

Comment: Since `setMyVector` only copies the reference, the caller mutate `vector` at a later time

Comment: @SteveKuo How is that possible? I kept update/set methods `private` so that it can only be called in the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

By making the vector instance as private and providing setter as private with getter as public would be the correct path in my opinion. 
For the :

```
List<T> readOnlyList = Collections.unmodifiableList(myList);
```

it will readnoly instance, however, it will still allow the access to other classes to call  add/set/remove methods but calling these methods results in UnsupportedException being raised.

Also, based on your requirement, you are looking for the updation of the vector / addition of new elements in it. So may by look for concurrent package to make it safer in doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to give copy of your Vector rather than giving original reference of your Vector Like following:

```
Vector vector = // your vector object in your class 
public Vector<String> getMyVercorObject(){
     return (Vector<String>)vector.clone() ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use `Vector` internally, only expose mutations (add, remove, etc) using methods, and only return an unmodifiable view using an interface (`List`). Such an implementation might look like this (for example sake let's say the elements are strings):

```
private final List<String> list = new Vector<String>();

/** Adds the specified element. */
public void addElement(String element) {
    list.add(element);
}

/** Replaces all elements. */
public void setElements(List<String> newElements) {
    list.clear();
    list.addAll(newElements);
}

/** Returns all elements. */
public List<String> getElement() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
}
```

In this way your class has full access to the list, while external entities can only mutate using the public methods.

Note that `Vector` is pretty much not used. If you require a thread safe list then consider `ArrayList` in conjunction with `synchronizedList`:

```
private final List<String> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
```